# Total of Male and Female in Grade 8 using sql, codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a problem about total in Yearlevel like total number of male and female in grade 7: [image]

I can count all by using codeigniter:

```html
  <h3> Total Students: <?php echo  $this->db->count_all('studentinformation'); ?></h3>
```

And then group them by using this:

```
SELECT Yearlevel, Sex, COUNT(Id) AS NumGender
FROM studentinformation
GROUP BY Sex, Yearlevel
```

My problem now is count in yearlevel total of grade7, grade 8 and then arrage them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for?

Use `case` expressions to do conditional counting:

```
SELECT Yearlevel,
       COUNT(*) AS studentcount,
       COUNT(case when Sex = 'Female' then 1 end) AS femalecount,
       COUNT(case when Sex = 'Male' then 1 end)   AS malecount
FROM studentinformation
GROUP BY Yearlevel
```

Comment: is this correct to view them?    <?php 
    foreach ($this->model_adminlogin->gendercountzx() as $ewa){
           echo $ewa->Yearlevel." ". $ewa->femalecount. " ".$$ewa->malecount."<br>";
    }
    
    ?>

Comment: @MarkDarylSenjuUchiiha, can't help you there - I don't know codeigniter.